# Check in android activity (at runtime) if strings.xml has changed from last execution

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, localization

My app must handle localization in sqlite db bacause of user can change translations at run time from inside the app so i cannot use resource files only, because they cannot be modified at runtime

I use resource file to store default translations and (at the moment) those translation are imported into db every time the app starts.

I retrieve and array containing all string in strings.xml
Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();

and cycle this array inserting new values and updating existing.
Unfortunately cycling every time all the strings is not an efficient way to update my db and so i would like to know if there is a way to perform import only if something has changed in original strings.xml without being forced, for example, to store the version number of the app in my db and check at startup if this number has changed and so perform the update

Comment: well string.xml can be only changed at compile time, so checking if you are upgrading your application should be enough, if I ve not misunderstood you

Comment: @blackbelt you mean checking versioncode of the app? I tought about that but for delevoping purpose i do not increase versioncode every time i modify strings.xml

Comment: but then you are not releasing it either

Answer (score 0):

The strings.xml which is located at res/values **CANNOT** be changed during runtime. Modification of that is possible only before compiling.

If you do want to store strings , look at [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You can , for example , store the state of current translation, and check for any changes

Comment: I know that and bacause of that i use db to store my translation. But i have to import default translation from strings.xml every time the app starts because if a default translation in strings.xml has changes i have to update my db. I only want to do it in an efficent way, not every time the app starts

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned that the contents of `strings.xml` cannot be changed at runtime so I'll ignore that.

If you want to monitor the file for changes between versions to trigger an automatic update of you language database the best way would be to have an entry in it specifically designed to record the current version. You can put a value at the top of your resource file such as:

```
<string name="current_string_language_resources_version">3</string>
```

And then when you load the values into your database also store that value.

On start you should compare the two values and they are different then import the stored value and remember to update the saved version number/string/whatever.

Depending on whether or not the various language options upgrade together or independently you could keep the value in an XML all on its own (to be shared) or in each individual language option's XML. Just make sure to remember to increment the version number wherever it is when you make changes.

Comment: Thank you @invisible but this is a solution similar to store versioncode in db, upgrade it every time i change strings.xml and then check it at startup if it has changed! I would like to know if i can find another way. Maybe it is simply not possibile

Comment: @on35, Like I said in the last paragraph it depends on if you store all your stings on one file or many separate files. If you don't want to go down the version number route then you could perhaps get a hash of the XML file (can't actually remember off hand if you can access resource files as a `File`) or other calculation on the contents but you will need to store some sort of state value somewhere to know if things have been modified. There's no way around that other than to read and compare the entire file's contents which is basically as much work as you are currently doing.

Comment: @on35, Myabe you need to rewrite your question to make it clearer what it is you want *and don't want* to do. Also the reasoning behind wanting to do it this way. It may be that you are overcomplicating something that has a much cleaner/simpler solution.

Comment: unfortunately the HASH way is not possible because the is no way to calculate the checksum of the file from inside the app because all is compiled

Comment: So to clarify - you want a way to test if the values have changed without manually incrementing a version or similar counter and also without comparing the values saved against the values read from the XML?

Comment: Yes that's the deal! I rephrased the question to be more clear (i hope)